# How to disable embedded google web viewer full screen option

Tags: iframe

i am using embedded google viewer with iframe to display pdf,i want to remove full screen popout from it and how could i disable right click in iframe.

itried doing many thing but nothing is working out,my pdf's url are store in db.

and i 'm using like this

```
 <iframe id="iframe" class="embed-responsive-item item" src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo $_SESSION['result'][$id]['content_url'];?>&embedded=true#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

some one help me out[image: how to remove full screen button]